# How can I tell if an int[] has not had anything assigned to it yet?

Tags: c#, arrays, null, arraylist

If I have this:

```
int[] lstAFewInts = new int[NUMBER_OF_STARS_IN_THE_MILKY_WAY];
```

...and I want to exit a method if it has had no values assigned to it yet, how do I test that? Is it:

```
if (lstAFewInts[0] == null)
```

...or???

Comment: an `int` is not a nullable type, so the default would be 0.

Comment: For `Strings` you can check with `.length()`

Comment: Checking for 0 won't work for me, because that is a valid value for the elements to have.

Comment: Do you need per element, or per array initialization checks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't rely on a value of 0 to specify an empty element, and if you can change the existing definitions, you can use an array of nullable ints - `int?[]`:

```
int?[] lstAFewInts = new int?[NUMBER_OF_STARS_IN_THE_MILKY_WAY];
```

Now all values will be `null` until assigned a number - any number:

```
bool atLeastOneAssigned = lstAFewInts.Any(i => i.HasValue);
```

Answer (score 8):

My advice: **raise the level of abstraction.**

```
class LazyArray<T>
{
    private T[] array;
    private int size;
    public LazyArray(int size) { this.size = size; }
    public bool IsInitialized { get { return this.array != null; } }
    public T this[int x] 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return this.array == null ? default(T) : this.array[x];
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.array == null) this.array = new T[size];
            this.array[x] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And you're done: you have an array of arbitrary size and you know whether it has been used yet or not:

```
void M()
{
    var myArray = new LazyArray<int>(whatever);
    while(whatever)
    {
        if (whatever) myArray[whatever] = whatever;
    }
    if (myArray.IsInitialized) 
        whatever;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
default(T)  // i.e., default(int)
```

Will give you the default value for a given type, in your case, `int`.  However, as `int` is a value type there is no way to distinguish between a default value of 0 and an assigned value of 0.

Are you sure you're going about this the best way possible?  Something like a `Dictionary<something, int>` would give you a better idea if something has been assigned or not as the key would not exist if it hasn't.  This of course assumes that you have unique keys to use, but judging from the name of your constant, the star's name may be a good key to use.

Also...

```
int[] lstAFewInts = new int[NUMBER_OF_STARS_IN_THE_MILKY_WAY];
```

The number of stars in our galaxy is estimated to be about 100 billion.  That's about 400GB you're allocating.  I see you running out of memory in the near future :)

Comment: Or you can *invent* some default value for you application and initialiaze array with a that value. (ex: int. MaxValue)

Comment: @Tigran: using special magic numbers for values that you're *sure* will never occur normally is a long-established source for annoying bugs. That's why we have Nullable<T>, which allows us to specify an explicitly invalid value - null.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: Well, if you're *sure* then it shouldn't be a problem.  It's the loose definition of *sure* that is often used which is a source of bugs :)  You're right though, `int?` is better in this case, assuming there isn't a better high level approach that could be taken.

Comment: Yes, well, italics simply don't convey the level of sarcasm I was going for. :)

Comment: Introduction of nullable type introduces one more possible state for the value. I would definetely prefer non nullable approach if I have reasonable amount of information about te system I'm operating on. And finally `null` just another possible value and will not help you to avoid evil/ wrong code in a any way.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are initialized to their default type.  Since int is a value type, that means it's initialized to the default for ints, which is 0.  There is no way to know if this was assigned by someone or it's initial value.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (lstAFewInts.All(i => i == 0))
{
    // No value, except possibly 0, has been assigned.  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the stated requirement.  It checks if *all* the values are 0, not a specific value.

Comment: I think that is specifically what was required.
“[H]ow do I test that […] it has had no values assigned to it yet.”

Comment: @Chris Farmer: Thanks, I thought it looked kinda 'off'.

Comment: Well, it may be worded a bit confusingly, but this line disagrees with you: `lstAFewInts[0]`.  It seems to me that the OP wants to check if an *element* in the array has been assigned yet.

Comment: Yes. But it was implied that he wanted to extend his code to perform the check on the *entire* array. That was the purpose of the question.

Comment: Well, to be fair, if we have to rely on implied requirements (and apparently we do) I can't say this is wrong.  I removed the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nullable int instead.

```
int?[] lstAFewInts = new int?[NUMBER_OF_STARS_IN_THE_MILKY_WAY];
```

Then

```
lstAFewInts[0].HasValue; // false
```

Of course, if you had a loop you could check every index to see whether it was assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays will be initialized to null for their type, BUT there is no such thing as a NULL int! So all the values will be initialized to 0, I think. You COULD check to see if the first value is 0 but that's not ideal since 0 may be something you want to use.

If possible I would rethink it and declare the array (it will be NULL until initialized to whatever size) and only initialize is when you add a value to it. Then you could check:

```
if (lstAFewInts)
```

returns NULL;